# Android. MediaPlayer. Audio stream doesn`t work with Wi-Fi connection

Tags: android

I have one problem.

I have an application, which should play some mp3 file. This mp3 file is located in Internet.

So application play this file, when internet connection is 3G/EDGE, but doesn`t play this mp3 file when connection type is Wi-Fi.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: do you see any exception? post your code and and logcat output if you see any error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you activate the option to keep wifi on during sleep ? If note may be your wifi just stop when you lock your phone.